# Sql results into php array

Tags: php, sql, mysql, arrays, unique

I would like to create an array (in php) from sql results like this:
We have the sql-table "Posts" which stores the **Name** and the **Message**.Example:

> Name | Message
>
> John | Hello
>
> Nick | nice day
>
> George | Good bye
>
> John | where

What i want is to **output the names of people who have posted a message but dont display the same names more than 1 time**.
So the output would be John,Nick,George.
(From these records, we see that John has posted 2 messages, but at the final output, we see only one time his name).

Is this somehow possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using mysql_ functions, pdo, mysqli....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql = <<<END
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Posts
END;
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . ' - ' . mysql_error());
$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $names[] = $row[0];
}
print_r($names);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

You could run a SQL query to just select the distinct names, and nothing else:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Posts;
```

This will give you a result set consisting of distinct Names values, with each unique value only being returned 1 time in the set.

Comment: Thanks,
In fact i already use a query to show the results, so i would like to use an array so to store the unique values (so dont to do a second array).
?

Comment: You mean just extracting the unique values out of an existing array, eg array_unique (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

Comment: Yeah, if you only want to use the original query, you'll need to 1) create an array consisting of all the names in your original query (basically how Cletus demonstrated), then 2) use the array_unique function that K Prime posted to remove duplicates from that array.

Comment: Yes,but could you explain it more?
Look,the query is eg: $query = dquery('SELECT * FROM POSTS'); (the real table has more columns so thats why i write *) and then:
foreach ($query as $res){
echo ''; etc..
}
After this i want to display eg:
echo 'People who posted:..';
how could i add them at the array,but only 1 time and to display directly the name? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to get the count you will need to aggregate using group by:

`SELECT
        NAME
    ,   COUNT(*) as Posts
FROM
        Posts
GROUP BY
        NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL if you are not averse to group BY

```
select count(name) as N, name from posts group by name ;
```

People having more than 1 post

```
select count(name) as N, name from posts group by name having N > 1 ;
```